# TypeError: getElementById is null

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, referenceerror

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var image = document.getElementById(image);
            var desc = document.getElementById(desc);
            var images = ["http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg"]
            var descs = ["1", "2"]
            var num = 0;
            var total = images.length;
            function clicked(){
                 num = num + 1;
                 if (num > total){
                    num = 0;
                 }
                 image.src = images[num];
                 desc.innerHTML = images[num];
            }
            document.getElementById(submit).onclick(clicked());
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div><h2>Project |</h2><h2> | herbykit</h2></div>
    <div>
        <button id="submit">Next</button><br/>
        <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg" height="20%" width="50%"/>
        <p id="desc">first desc.</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The line "document.getElementById(submit).onclick(clicked());" throws an error
    "ReferenceError: submit is not defined"

When I tried accessing buttons in general
[through getElementsByClassName & getElementsByTagName]
it gave an error of "ReferenceError: button is not defined"

Using strings in getElementById it throws the error "getElementById is null"

I found several questions and answers to this.

Only one of them I understood how to implement, due to the use of PHP and that being the error on most others. Other solutions I found involved errors numerically.
On this error I tried a fix of printwindow.document.getElementById(..etc
This gives me an error of "ReferenceError: printwindow is not defined"

Comment: `'submit'` You need to pass as string.

Comment: When I did, it gave me the error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Comment: This is because you are trying to find elements before they exist into DOM. Place your script right before closing `</bdoy>` tag.

Comment: You have to call it after the DOM has loaded (or) include the `script` tag at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it gives me the error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onClick is not a function" I tried changing it to onclick but I got the same error. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: It gives me the same error when I do `document.getElementById('submit').onclick(clicked);`
When I do clicked() inside onClick, it shows the second picture and the link to it. When I do clicked inside onClick, it shows the first picture and description, both giving the same error

Comment: @herbykit Try `onclick = clicked`

Comment: It appears to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers run JavaScript as soon as possible in order to speed up rendering. So when you receive this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var image = document.getElementById(image); // Missing quotes, typo?
```

... in runs intermediately. There's no `<foo id="image">` on page yet, so you get `null`. Finally, you get the rest of the page rendered, including:

```
<img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg" height="20%" width="50%"/>
```

It's too late for your code, which finished running long ago.

You need to bind a window.onload even handler and run your code when the DOM is ready (or move all JavaScript to page bottom, after the picture).

Answer (score 0):

It should be `document.getElementById('submit').onclick(clicked());`

Comment: Yeah I missed the other comments (I think by timing but possibly negligence). looks like moving that script tag to the bottom should do the trick. It's standard practice to put scripts at the bottom when you can for the purposes of loading the DOM before you load scripts

Comment: It's a standard practice... but for improved page speed, when loading external JavaScript files. Code that depends on having DOM ready normally takes care of that explicitly, no matter where you put it later.

Answer (score 0):

your must enclose the id you are searching for in quotes:

```
document.getElementById('ID_to_look_up');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing javascript before your 'body' rendered. Thus document.getElementById("submit") would return null. Because there are no "submit" DOM element yet.

One solution is to move your javascripts under 'body', Or use JQuery with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

Your variable also has scope problem, your function cannot access variable declared outside this function with 'var' declaration. If you really need that variable, you should remove 'var' declaration. 
A better way is to move all your variable inside clicked function. like following code

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <div><h2>Project |</h2><h2> | herbykit</h2></div>
    <div>
        <button id="submit">Next</button><br/>
        <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg" height="20%" width="50%"/>
        <p id="desc">first desc.</p>
   </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">            
            function clicked(){
                var image = document.getElementById("image");
                var desc = document.getElementById("desc");    
                var images = ["http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiD.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/XAgFPiE.jpg"];   
                var descs = ["1", "2"];
                var num = 0;
                var total = images.length;     
                num = num + 1;
                if (num > total){
                    num = 0;
                }
                image.src = images[num];
                desc.innerHTML = images[num];
            }
            document.getElementById("submit").onclick = clicked;
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @sunlight07 No, just a noob