# How to access an HTML element within a self invoked function.

Tags: javascript, html, brackets

I am pretty new to JavaScript so I don't know the ins and outs of the language but I do have some knowledge of it. I created a self invoked function that would sort an array of zip-codes and then output it to a div element in the html file.

Unfortunately, the output isn't going into the div element because the function is executed before the html elements is ready, therefor it doesn't exist.

Is there anyway that I could access the div element within the function without having to use Window.Load, etc?

Thank you! click on the link below to view my function.

[Screenshot of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmcdm.jpg)

Comment: Add the script at the bottom of the <body> tag instead of at the top

Comment: You can move your `<script>` to the end of the closing `</body>` tag (just before it) - at that point, it will find the existing element by its `id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: getElementById is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972488/typeerror-getelementbyid-is-null)

Comment: @ochi How is that post even relevant?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: You should add the relevant code no a screenshot See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Nate did you read it?  it's the same issue: trying to invoke a call to `getElementyById(...)` before the element is rendered into the DOM - the solution suggested is the same in both: move your JS to the end of the body tag

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that I could access the div element within the
>   function without having to use Window.Load, etc?

Just move that code to the end of your html - after elements in question.
For example after `</body>`

Comment: after `</body>` or just before it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can't access the DOM if it doesn't exist in that moment.

I know I know, don't use `window.onload`. But I assure you this **is** different than waiting for the DOM to load and then follow up with your calculations.

You can have a function evaluate something, then actually hang on the result and wait, and then finally fill the innerHTML when the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired... or perhaps something of similar flavour, have a look at this.

```
<script>
    const calculations = (function () {
        // Super smart calculations...

        var output = "Result of smart calculations";

        function findWhereOutputGoes() {
            return document.getElementById('output-div');
        }

        return {
            output: output,
            findWhereOutputGoes: findWhereOutputGoes,

        }
    })();

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // Fires as soon as DOM has loaded
        calculations.findWhereOutputGoes().innerHTML = calculations.output;
    });
</script>
<div id="output-div">

</div>
```